# Unable to require('azure') 2.0.0-preview

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

**Version Information**

- Node.js: v4.6.0
- [Azure](https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-node): 2.0.0-preview
- MacOS Sierra (10.12.4 Beta)

**Problem**
I am getting the following error when I try to `require('azure');`. Using 1.2.0-preview works as expected, but I need to use 2.0. Any pointers?

```
/my_path/node_modules/azure/lib/azure.js:1145
let AzureGraph = require('azure-graph');
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Posting it for the benefit of others.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/2141

Basically, the Azure package needs you to use Node 6.10.2.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that others can benefit from it. Thanks